# How to make dataTable rows interactible?

Tags: html, reactjs, datatable, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a React component where I have a [Bootstrap data table](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html). I want to add a button in each row that triggers a function when clicked. However, when I pass the reference to my function in the html, the function does not triggered on clicking the button. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?

The table data looks like this

```
export const ActiveUserList = ({ showModal }) => {
  const BootStrapTableData = {
  data: [
    {
      user: { name: 'Ananya Singh', desc: '@ananya.singh', img: img7 },
      contact: '+91 98765 43210',
      emailid: 'ananya.singh@example.com',
      action: { actionadd: 'add', actionedit: 'edit', actionremove: 'remove' },
    },
    {
      user: { name: 'Aryan Kapoor', desc: '@aryan.kapoor', img: img4 },
      contact: '+91 98765 43211',
      emailid: 'aryan.kapoor@example.com',
      action: { actionadd: 'add', actionedit: 'edit', actionremove: 'remove' },
    },
  ],
  columns: [
    {
      title: 'Profiles',
      data: 'user',
      render: function (data) {
        return (
          '<div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img class="rounded img-fluid me-3" src=' +
          data.img +
          ' alt=""/><div class="media-support-info"><h6 className="mb-0">' +
          data.name +
          '</h6><p className="mb-0">' +
          data.desc +
          '</p></div></div>'
        );
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      data: 'action',
      render: function (data) {
        return `<button type='button' onClick="${showModal}">Show</button>`;
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

In the columns properties, there is an **Action** columns which renders a html button on which I have passed a reference to my `showModal` function. But clicking on the button does nothing.

When I checked the html by inspecting the webPage, the button element is looking like this

```
<td>
   <button type="button" onclick="() => setHireFormVisible(true)">Show</button>
</td>
```

The `showModal` function translates to the actual function body that is `setHireFormVisible`

When I pass the function with `showModal()` like this then modal automatically opens up without clicking button

```
    {
        title: 'Action',
        data: 'action',
        render: function (data) {
            return `<button type='button' onClick="${showHireForm()}">Show</button>`;
        },
    },
```

How can I make this button interactible ?